# Query optimization; Table.Column = @Param OR @Param IS NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In WHERE clause when using condition like this Table.Column = @Param OR @Param IS NULL It does not use INDEX on Column.

Is it true and if so then how to write this kind of query which also use INDEX

Query Example

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 ...
FROM Table
WHERE (Col1 = @col OR @col IS NULL)
AND   (Col2 = @col2 OR @col2 IS NULL)
AND   (Col3 = @col3 OR @col3 IS NULL)
```

Any help.

Comment: Sorry for not formatting my question. Editor is not giving me options and preview. I am not sure why.

Comment: it doesn't improve the performance, but this condition may be written in more elegant way: col1=isnull(@col, col1)

Comment: Here is a very complete reference on the subject of dynamic search conditions: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html And you can easily see for yourself if a query uses an index by reviewing the execution plan in SSMS.

Comment: @heximal - The isnull method would return different results is there are nulls in the data.  The isnull method compares data with the equal operator.  Null does not equal null, so the row would be filtered out.  With the code from the original post, that row would be returned.  The isnull method cannot be considered "more elegant" if it doesn't generate the correct output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the generation of execution plans does not behave as you expect.

For that single query, a single plan is created.  In creating that plan the indexes to use are selected, and fixed.  It doesn't matter what parameters you provide, the same plan, same indexes, etc, are always used.

The otpimiser has *tried* to find the best plan that can fit all eventuallities, but by the nature of this type of query, there isn't one.  A characteristic born out by the plan you have not using an index at all.

The solution is to use dynamic SQL.  This feels untidy, but if you use parameterised queries with `sp_executesql`, it can actually be quite stuctured, and very performant.

Here is a link to a very useful article on the subject:  [dynamic search](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

It's very in depth, but it *is* a very robust approach to this problem.

Comment: This is what good ORM tools do under the hood. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 ...
FROM Table
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
    INTERSECT
    SELECT @col, @col2, @col3)
```

Intuitively, this seems like it should perform very badly, but SQL Server's query optimiser knows how to give `INTERSECT` special treatment, and internally translates it to (pseudo-SQL)

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 ...
FROM Table
WHERE (Col1, Col2, Col3) IS (@col, @col2, @col3)
```

as you can see in the query plan. If you have indices on these columns, they can and do get used.

I originally picked this up from Paul White's [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx) blog post, which may be an interesting further read.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't try this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 ...
FROM Table
WHERE Col1 = IsNull(@col,Col1)
AND Col2 = IsNull(@col2,Col2)
AND Col3 = IsNull(@col3,Col3)
```

About your question:
Your query analyzer say it don't use the index on column1,2,3 ? You made a index for all 3 columns? Then it should use it regardless the other `OR IS NULL`

Comment: In terms of generating the execution plan, this runs in to *exactly* the same behaviours as the OP is already experiencing.  In short, it doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: I don't have any doubts you are rights but don't understand why the execution plan don't use his index then anyway.

Comment: There is a link in my answer, to an article that explains this alot.  I tickle the surface in my answer, but to give a full and complete answer would be to write an article.  Best read the link, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Try to have index on all where clause columns and try to use the more structured query as given below:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 ... 
FROM Table 
WHERE Col1 = **COALESCE**(@col,Col1)
AND Col2 = **COALESCE**(@col2,Col2)
AND Col3 = **COALESCE**(@col3,Col3)
```

The COALESCE() function returns the first non-null argument so if STATUS is NULL it will return ''.

Comment: This won't make any difference for the reasons touched upon in my answer, and referenced by the article I linked.  *(And that was linked in a comment to the question.)*

Comment: There is also one more way around. But I dont think what feasibilty it will be on your prodcution enviorment. Make a index on the main table for the Primary Key. Then in your final query just provide a search on the primary key and put the records in temp. table. Now create an Index for all columns on the temp table. And finally write your select query from the temp table.